# Play 2.3 Ebean, @OneToMany relation with join

Tags: playframework, one-to-many, ebean

I have two classes as below.

```
@Entity 
public class A extends Model 
{ 
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String value; 

   @OneToMany(targetEntity = AB.class, mappedBy = "a", cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
   private List<AB> ab;
}

@Entity 
public class AB extends Model 
{ 
   @Id
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = A.class) 
   private A a; 

   private Integer type;
}
```

I want to get all A objects related to AB object where type for example is set to 3.

```
List<A> aList = A.find.where().join("AB").where().eq("AB.type", "3").findList();
```

And in result I have error:

```
[RuntimeException: Error getting BeanDescriptor for path join ajoin_b from models.A]
```

I was trying everythings, @JoinTable, @JoinColumn etc

I know that I can do it in directly by sql, by I want to know what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
A.find.fetch("ab").where().eq("t1.type", 3).findList();
```

The t1 got me for a while, but the generated SQL seemed to make the join table clear.  I'm using PostgreSQL.  I don't think you need to quote the 3, as AB.type is an integer (int in the DB).

This might work too.

```
A.find.where().eq("ab.type",3).findList()
```

Comment: I tried your proposals, but unfortunately, I had errors.
For 
    A.find.fetch("ab").where().eq("t1.type", 3).findList();
[RuntimeException: Error getting BeanDescriptor for path ab from models.A]

For second
   A.find.where().eq("ab.type",3).findList()
[PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:Unknown column 'ab.type' in 'where clause' Bind values:[3] Query was: select t0.id c0, t0.value c1 from a t0 where ab.type = ? ]

Comment: Try dropping all the extra attributes except for the cascade.
I've got @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL) on the A side and just @ManyToOne on the AB side.